# Retrieving values into different columns

Tags: sql, pivot-table

I've got a table that looks like this (but with thousands of rows)

[image]

I was wondering, if there is a way to retrieve my data so that it looks something like this (there might me more than 3 TimeStamps for one SessionId)

[image]

Note: I don't care which version of SQL is used for my answer.

Comment: How come you don't care which version of SQL is used? Aren't you going to use the answer?!?

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres you could aggregate the timestamps into an array:

```
select sessionid, 
       class,
       starttime,
       timestamps[1] as timestamp_1,
       timestamps[2] as timestamp_2,
       timestamps[3] as timestamp_3,
       timestamps[4] as timestamp_4
from (        
    select sessionid, 
           class,
           starttime, 
           array_agg(timestamp order by timestamp) as timestamps
    from the_table
    group by sessionid, class, starttime
) t
```

You can't have a dynamic number of columns in SQL. The number, types and names of all columns must be known to the database engine, when the query is parsed. It can't change during runtime.